# I want to move only cell of table in the same column

Tags: jquery

I want to move the cell of a table in the same column. The following is my jquery code - it is not working properly.

```
$("table tbody tr").sortable({
  axis: "y",
  items: 'td',
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: actually i want to move the single cell in the same column up and down but after dropping it it will move the the content of the cell in last column's cell